# Did the Sith die out with Sidious' death?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, sith, darth-sidious

It's evident that Sidious was confident in that he would be an eternal emperor and that there was no need for a successor but when his death came, did the Sith die out? I don't think Snoke and Kylo are actual Sith, Kylo fits the description of a Dark Jedi and Snoke seems to be something else.

Comment: Sure, same way Jedi dies with Yoda. Wasn't really a full Jedi by that point. Also, I'm tempted to close this question as either referring to further works, or opinion-based.

Comment: This question likely currently doesn't have an answer.